# How to share make targets between makefiles?

Tags: makefile

I have a git repo and each directory in the repo contains a makefile to build the project there. The makefiles are 90% the same, with a few minor tweaks.

In a normal programming language I'd split out the shared code into a library/shared module so I don't have to keep repeating myself. Is there a way to do this with makefiles, i.e. import a set of shared targets/functions somehow?

Comment: Look maybe at the [`include`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include) make directive.

Comment: You can also invoke make subprocesses via `$(MAKE)` and pass a particular makefile to parse via the `-f` parameter, e.g. `$(MAKE) -f ../common_path/GenericMakefile`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I really want to import, say, the `clean` target so that `make clean` against all Makefiles will delegate to the same shared target that actually implements `make clean`.

Comment: @lubgr Could I name a target, e.g. `$(MAKE) -f ../common_path/GenericMakefile clean`?

Comment: @alisap: "_I really want to import, say, the clean target_" fine, then simply create a `clean.mk` file with just the definition of the `clean` rule, and include it in any Makefile that needs it.

Comment: @allsap Yes, that should be possible. It's like an ordinary shell command, only the `$(MAKE)` part which is defined by make itself.

Comment: OK thanks RenaudPacalet/lubgr i'll try those approaches

Comment: Have a look at this `make` library, it might help you https://github.com/igagis/prorab
Basically, you can have targets declared as `myTarget::` and then you can have multiple targets with same name but different recepies.